# Test performance of a computer for maximum concurrent user allowance?

Tags: desktop-computer, diagnostic

**How can I test a pc to see how many concurrent users it can handle without performance issues?**

The users will be limited to 6 webpages or Tabs open and no audio/video streaming or downloading.

Any information from experience would be appreciated. We are upgrading to new systems and are trying one out before we by the lot..

Comment: if they arent streaming or downloading, what will they be doing?

Comment: @keltari Streaming or downloading Audio or video content. Strictly text and images can be viewed.